# Add non-google account to IAM and Email Senders of App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iam

I am trying to add a email sender account in Google App Engine. The domain is not a google apps domain.

When I try to add the account as an IAM user, it says the account must have a google account. When I try to make a Google account, it forces me to make a @gmail account as part of it.

Once all that was said and done, I am able to add my new email domain into IAM, but as soon as I save and refresh the page - it shows the @gmail alias I created. It won't let me add my own domain as an email sender because only the @gmail is in IAM.

Is this broken?

*UPDATED*
Turns out that I accidentally assigned a gmail account to the Google account as well and that was overriding the name. I went into the google account and removed Gmail from the products list and I was able to add the subdomain in IAM and as a valid sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not broken, just working as documented. From [Who can send mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail):

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of
>   the following:
>
> - The Gmail or G Suite Account of the user who is currently signed in
> - Any email address of the form `anything@[APP_NAME].appspotmail.com` or `anything@[APP_ALIAS].appspotmail.com`
> - Any email address listed in the GCP Console under [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings)
>
> All email addresses on the [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings) list need
>   to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts.

One option would be to get your domain under Google domain hosting or G-Suite, thus meeting one of the quoted restrictions, donno if that's acceptable for you.

These sender address restrictions and other restrictions associated with sending email through the GAE Mail API) are probably not applicable if sending email through one of the Google's 3rd party email provider services: [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mailgun), [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mailjet) and [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sendgrid). At least such restrictions are not mentioned in these docs. So that could be another option to consider.

Comment: Strange. This new domain is a sub domain of a domain that is already in IAM. I must be missing something then. Let me check on it and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: After more research, our naked domain was added there pre-IAM and before organizations existed.

Comment: Thanks, you lead me down the right path and I am resolved.